# (Search option not working) Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement the Google Maps API onto my website. Google Maps loads,  however search option still seems to be at large due to the below error message

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined**

on following line:

> **`var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);`**

**What is it that needs to be corrected to get this code going ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>


      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #CCC;
      } 

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">

        <script>
            function initMap() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},            
            zoom: 13, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      }

      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      //function initAutocomplete() {
        //  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        //  center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        //  zoom: 13,
        //  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        //});

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });


    </script>   
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initMap" async defer></script>                     
  </body>
</html>
```

***Any help would be highly appreciated !!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asynchronously loading the API.  You need to put all the code that depends on the API in the callback function (`initMap`).

Also, you didn't read this comment, you aren't including the places library:

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kkq7g7fj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: {
      lat: 44.540,
      lng: -78.546
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
  // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
  // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
  //function initAutocomplete() {
  //  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  //  center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
  //  zoom: 13,
  //  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  //});

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put whole your code to the `initMap` bc `google` will be defined only after [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/intx/en_uk/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html?utm_source=HouseAds&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2015-Geo-EMEA-LCS-GEO-MAB-DeveloperTargetedHouseAds&utm_content=Developers&gclid=Cj0KEQiAsP-2BRCFl4Lb2NTJttEBEiQAmj2tbYLprNvhXoggqbEZqJy2PtisiJ345k-d0bZFeBP37ZcaAqvS8P8HAQ) script will be loaded on the page.

Also added small verification to make it worked and no errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>


      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #CCC;
      } 

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }

    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        
        <script>
            function initMap() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},            
            zoom: 13, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      

      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      //function initAutocomplete() {
        //  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        //  center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        //  zoom: 13,
        //  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        //});

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        if (!google.maps.places) {
          return false;
        }
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
}

    </script>   
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initMap" async defer></script>                         
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @meleshko - no luck mate.