# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to to load in markers from a geoJSON file onto my map, the map loads fine, but keep getting an error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

at this line...

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've read [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174540/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined) other questions on this, and most of it deal with how you need to include the google maps script before your map code. I've tried including it in my head and right above my map container, but no luck. The map itself actually does load, just the markers from my JSON file don't.

HTML/JS Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game Industry Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-defualt navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Game Industry Map</a>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From Software, Naughty Dog, Bethesda Game Studios, BreakAway Games..." id="query" name="query" value="">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='content-container'>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="company-info">
        <!--To do...-->
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 34.029602, lng: -118.452416},
            zoom: 13
        });
        map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
<footer>Created by <a href="#">My Name</a>.</footer>
</html>
```

geoJSON File

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [34.019602, -118.452416]},
      "properties": {
        "company-logo": "images/activision.png",
        "company-name": "Activision Publishing Inc",
      }
    },

    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [34.028230, -118.471270]},
      "properties": {
        "company-logo": "images/naughtydog.png",
        "company-name": "Naughty Dog Inc",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Search option not working) Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909352/search-option-not-working-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include the google library before the script calling the library:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 34.029602, lng: -118.452416},
            zoom: 13
        });
        map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**Edit**

You are defining a callback here : `/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap`

This will call your `initMap()` method once google maps has loaded all its components.

But you are calling the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` outside this function, hence, when `google` isnot yet loaded.

You should try to include your `addDomListener` call in your `initMap()` call !

Comment: In the google api docs they have the script tags at the bottom: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: I tried that already, but unfortunately didn't work. The map itself loads either way, just not the markers no matter where I include the library.

Comment: ok sorry, it's because your are calling initMap() as a callback, and `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` is not in the initMap() function, so google is not yet defined when you call it

Comment: Oh wait yeah, I tried that too earlier but I got a "Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined" I didn't read it closely thinking it was just the same "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" error, but doing it again just now when you said I saw it wasn't google but initialize this time and that was because the function was called initMap not initialize. None the less thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are close, first off you need to add a listener using `google.maps.event.addListerner()`, then you need to add the listener to the DOM using `google.maps.events.addDomListner()`

`addListener` is async, so you need to write it with a callback. Here is an example:

```
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center: myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });

marker.setMap(map);

// Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(9);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**Relevant Links:**

http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_marker_click

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can just write:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE"></script>
```

(without the callback).
The API_KEY is also not necessary.
In a public Maps JavaScript API app it is therefore strongly recommended to add a referrer restriction to any key used in a production system, especially public facing ones, and only authorize the domain, host or even full file URL of your app.